# faultCode 105 faultString XML error: Invalid document end at line 1, column 1

Tags: php, joomla1.5, xml-rpc

I have facing problem to access xmlrpc. Whenever I tried to access xmlrpc through this `http://localhost/joomla/xmlrpc` link I got following error:

> faultCode 105 faultString XML error: Invalid document end at line 1, column 1

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<methodResponse> 
  <fault>
    <value> 
      <struct>
        <member>
          <name>faultCode</name> 
          <value><int>105</int></value> 
        </member> 
        <member> 
          <name>faultString</name> 
          <value><string>XML error: Invalid document end at line 1, column 1</string></value> 
        </member> 
      </struct> 
    </value> 
  </fault> 
</methodResponse>
```

I am using joomla 1.5. Does anyone have this relevant error?

Comment: Whenever you see this error, you need to show you you create the XML-RPC request. Because the error is in the XML of the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just 'browsing' to the address of the xmlrpc folder? It looks from the response like you didn't submit an xml 'request' document to the url. XMLRPC requires that you post a request in the form of commands via an xml file.

Comment: thanks, looks like the hint for the level 13 of python challenge:)